# dynamically change the dijit.form.NumberSpinner Range

Tags: dojo

I am in the need of changing the range(min and max value) of the NumberSpinner dynamically according to the selection made through some FilteringSelect.

In the onChange event of the FilteringSelect, I have coded something like as follows:-

```
    spinner.attr("minvalue","10");
    spinner.attr("maxvalue","50");
```

Is this (**minvalue** & **maxvalue**) the correct attribute to set ?
Please note that I am using dojo 1.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the "constraints" member.

```
spinner.attr("constraints", {max: 50, min: 10});
```

Note that it overwrites the old constraints. For example, if the constraints were `{max: 2, min: 0, places: 1}`, the above will effectively discard the "places" constraint.

You can overcome that by first retrieving the old constraints, making the changes you want, and then setting it again:

```
var constraints = spinner.attr("constraints");
constraints.max = 20;
constraints.min = 10;
spinner.attr("constraints", constraints);
```